# what's the structure of this sentence "condition being, that..."?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

What is the structure of this sentence (his only condition being, that they were new ones) in this context below (from perfume 2015 movie script)?

He did not differentiate between what are good smells from bad,
at least not yet

he was very greedy.

the goal was to possess everything the world had to offer in odors.
**his only condition being, that they were new ones**.

[image: a part of script]

Comment: What makes you think there's anything to that but "his only condition *was* that they were new ones", please?

Comment: I'm persian and it had a strange structure for me, so i needed to know it's grammer and structure sir.

Comment: Thanks and then that belonged somewhere like English Language Learners. Despite that, what did your translators leave unclear, please?

Comment: Thank you, the meaning of "being" was unclear. I don't care about meaning althogh, but i do care for grammer and structure.

Answer (score -1):

I found my answer here:

[Clause for the phrase "Being that ..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391964/clause-for-the-phrase-being-that)

I think my sentence had a "absolute construction".